# Can I expand an APFS volume across multiple drives

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, apfs

I have installed a 2nd SSD in a Mac running Mojave.

Is it possible to expand the current active volume across the 2nd SSD?
I would rather do this and have a single volume instead of moving home directories etc.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'd say no, unless you RAID the drives first - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309739/apfs-container-over-multiple-physical-disks and https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/dskua23150fd/mac